# Libre office Calc OR is not working according to documentation

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Accoring to [libre office calc documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Logical_Functions#OR) this should return true: `=OR(FALSE;TRUE)` but my Libre Office return only `#NAME?`. I have tried many different examples, they all end up the same and Calc refuses to work with `OR`.

If I change `OR` to `AND` everything is ok and formula results in TRUE or FALSE.

[image: Calc]

So, formula `=AND(12<11;13>22;45=45)` ends with `FALSE` and formula `=OR(12<11;13>22;45=45)` ends with `#NAME?`.

I already think calc doesn't have "OR"... but is it possible? What am i doing wrong?

--

**The reason was actually the "Use English function Names" setting, which is canceled by default.**

But, look at my default function names (language: Slovak)

[image]

Everything except OR (selected on screenshot) is in English. This is definitely a bad default value (uncheck Use English function Names) and formulas should be clearly in English by default. This way I can expect something to stop working for me at any moment, because someone translated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a language-settings issue.

First, check your Formula Options (Menu Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula, under "Formula Options"). Check if "Use English function Names" is activated - i suppose it isn't. Your screenshot indicates that "OR" isn't recognized as function name, and this is most likely due to the fact that you're using localized function names instead of the English ones.

Additionally, you may have to change "TRUE" and "FALSE" to the localized equivalent. Even with English function names enabled, the boolean values follow the localization settings.

Alternatively, keep your language settings and use the function wizard (or the context help) to identify the localized function names.

Comment: Thank you very much ... yes, this setting helped me. I have no idea who invented this, but using translated functions, while maybe 5% of names are translated is a total fail. So everything written today will be working until someone translate some next function names to my language? Every other function I see in function list is in English (including TRUE and FALSE) ... This is a really unfortunate default setting.